# My cypress assertion test is failing, but it still shows green arrow

Tags: cypress

As seen here, It shows green arrow, but test has failed.I need to click on the test to see result:

[image]

Without clicking on test, it seems as if test has passed:

[image]

I want the test to be shown in red color or red arrow mark

Comment: Found the answer:  Had to comment this in index.js (in support folder of cypress)

`Cypress.on("fail", (err, runnable) => {
   return false;
});`

Answer (score 0):

You can use cy.should. Now when assert fail, test will fail

```
cy.should(() => {
  expect(result).to.equal(true) 
});
```